# Knockoutjs dependencies

Tags: knockout.js

How can I dump the dependency graph when using knockoutjs? I am having trouble understanding why my views do not update when my data model changes, and my attempts to simulate this in jsfiddle failed (the dependencies worked correctly in the simplified code). I am looking for a way to dump the dependencies in the debugger (or onto the console) so that I can get a better understanding of what's going on. Stepping through the code was a painful and unrewarding experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "dependency graph" in this case, but if you're referring to the objects you're binding to you could have a look at [Mat McLoughlin's Knockout Inspector](https://github.com/mat-mcloughlin/knockout-inspector) which can be really helpful to debug your data subscriptions and data changes. Not sure that's what you're asking for, but I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly what you want, you could always subscribe to view model properties and spit out changed values. Also, when using computed variables, I found it useful to manually trigger dependencies.

Comment: My data structure is a list of objects (hundreds, or more), each object with some complex state. Various user interactions modify object state. I have filters that select a subset of the list based on object state. Manual subscriptions seem hard to maintain in this kind of an environment, unless I am missing some clever way of handling it.

Comment: you could always look at breezejs to handle the entire object graph for you. I am finding it difficult to understand what the actual problem is.